# Phase unwrapping fringes

Tags: python, image-processing, wolfram-mathematica, physics, phase

I have one third of an image which contains vertical interference fringes (the fringes are vertical lines with about one pixel width):

[image]

I'm looking for software solution, i. e. python or Mathematica code to unwrap the phase to get clear image without fringes, phase contrast image.

I found the article in python: https://www.kaggle.com/code/kmader/unwrapping-signals-phase-shift-overflow. In this link, under "In [9]:" there is unwrapped image:

[image]

I wanted to do the same with vertical lines in my picture.

In the picture there are vertical lines (bright and dark, side by side), I've marked two of them with blue and green:

[image]

Comment: is that the best picture you have? do you think *that* resolution and contrast are sufficient?

Comment: They're pixel values to work with. From top-left 268 pixels across, 105 down.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz It's the picture I wanted to work with.

Comment: please review "phase unwrapping", its assumptions and preconditions, how it is implemented.

Comment: Phase unwrapping appears to be a microscopy technique for increasing contrast.  https://www.scientifica.uk.com/learning-zone/a-guide-to-phase-contrast

Comment: That said, I might be overlooking something about "unwrapping the phase" — perhaps Malum can clarify.

Comment: I've edited the post to clarify what I mean.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen "phase *unwrapping*" is unrelated to other "phase" things, except for phase being involved. phase unwrapping has nothing to do with enhancing contrast. "phase unwrapping" is a term in literature. here's a picture to explain it: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Example-of-phase-unwrapping-process-a-Wrapped-phase-b-Unwrapped-phase_fig1_5605281 (look at the plots and how they relate, ignore the application)

Comment: I've discovered DHM Utilities in Fiji program (ImageJ). Does anyone have experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `skimage.restoration.unwrap_phase()`. An example for its use is given [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/filters/plot_phase_unwrap.html).

Please note that phase unwrapping of noisy data is always a difficult process that usually requires some assumptions of the noise and how to handle it. Sometimes it outright is not feasible. Unwrapping of 2D-data may even be impossible even if there is no noise as one can have vertices in the wrapped data that cannot be resolved during unwrapping.

Comment: The `skimage.restoration.unwrap_phase()` appears to have less settings than `np.unwrap()`  function.

Comment: Does np.unwrap work for 2D arrays? I thought np.unwrap was for perfect (without noise) 1D data, rather than noisy data with potentially more dimensions.

Comment: The np.unwrap() work for 2D arrays. My post contains link to the examples.

Answer (score -1):

There is no phase information.

I took your data apart into even and odd columns. I also stretched the value range. Take a look:

[image: side by side]

Here is your original data, with stretched value range:

[image]

Both of these pictures I made are illustrations/plots, not data.

Since you won't tell us what this data is, how it was made, what is being imaged, we can't help you any more than this.

Comment: I try to collect again this data. They come from old surface profiler, it's MEMS device.